# which database and encoding scheme would be appropriate for audio data storage?

Tags: java, database, audio

I have experience of relational database systems storing text data, and building applications for them. I have heard that relational databases don't really work for audio(multimedia) databases and some encoding scheme is also required. So any guidance in this regard would be very helpful.
I want to stream the audio, get it in chunks, and planning to use ogg vorbis codec for the same. For streaming audio data, I think one cannot think of storing the file on server and simply providing a path in the database pointing to them. If I do so then: Audio files are large, so without compressing them, sending them over a channel won't work for normal internet connections, neither uploading them would work.

Comment: Audio is raw binary data; most databases offer a "blob" data type for storing this kind of thing.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Why do you need to put audio into a database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to know or do. You want to simple store audio (like the contents of an .wav) ? You want to store more information or just the contents? You want to retrieve the informations or the audio? You will stream the audio, get it in chunks ?

Answer (score 1):

It can work (see BLOB http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object), but you could also use files for the actual data, and just store a varchar pointing to the files.

Encoding should be avoided, since that adds the extra step of decoding for each use.

Answer (score 1):

When you hear `relational databases don't really work for audio(multimedia)` that probably means that storing a lot of binary data directly in a database causes poor performance and maintenance headache. For example, if you have terrabytes of data in RDB it will be hard to backup, move and scale.

You, however, can store BLOB data in RDB but I would recommend you consider file storage with DB just pointing to the file. You can use S3 (with good cache server) or local filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Various meta info about an audio clip can be stored in a database all right, and this makes sense since you can reasonably query it.

Audio clips themselves are usually huge (several megs), and generally you cannot index them. So there's no point storing them directly in a database, and if you do, it slows things down. The only upside of having audio data directly in the database is transactions / locking, an unlikely advantage in most scenarios.

Some databases (in particular, Oracle) can store BLOBs 'offline', that is, not in the table space, but as files on other media. This helps performance a bit. Still if you store audio data as BLOBs, you can only access them via a database interface.

If you store your audio separately, in the DB you can just store file names. You can serve audio data using a different mechanism, more appropriate for audio or easier for clients (e.g. http). The downside is that you have less control over them: a link may accidentally be broken, and you don't have transactions that delete a file or roll it back. (Usually you run a periodic garbage collection process that deletes unreferenced files.)

Unless you describe your application in more detail, it's hard to give more specific advice.

Comment: How about using some other types of databases like object relational databases like Cassandra or Hbase of hdoop?